# Transparent SQLite Data Compression

Tags: c, compression, sqlite, zlib

I am looking for an existing solution for transparent SQLite 3 zlib compression using [a custom VFS implementation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html) and [a custom IO methods implementation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/io_methods.html).

Is anyone aware of an existing project that already does that, or will I have to roll my own? I vaguely remember seeing something similar a year ago, but can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use a compressed filesystem via FUSE, such as [FuseCompress](https://github.com/tex/fusecompress) or [compFUSEd](http://freecode.com/projects/compf), which transparently compresses the sqlite file using zlib, lzo, or bzip2.

**Edit:** There is also a separate solution that you can load as an extension, [sqlitecompress](http://lserinol.googlepages.com/sqlitecompress).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option for me, as I don't have access to the system itself and have to compress on the application level.

Comment: +1 for sqlitecompress. I'm curious - how does it handle WHERE queries? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The [Compressed and Encrypted Read-Only Database (CEROD)](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/prosupport.html#compress) SQLite extension does compression, and is available from the authors of SQLite. It is a commercial add-on.